# How to show the photo right after uploading the file using <input name="photo" type="file" />?

Tags: html, css, file-upload, input

Currently, after uploading an image file by clicking the "**Browse...**" button, it only displays the uploaded file name, but not the photo itself. Is it possible to show the uploaded photo at the same time?

Comment: Thanks, Jatin! I had tried searching for it, but obviously did not hit the right key words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u have to make use of script with your HTML code ,which will trigger the div to display the image ,consider this jsfiddle

```
          function readURL(input) 
          {
              if (input.files && input.files[0]) 
            {
               var reader = new FileReader();

               reader.onload = function (e) 
                     {
                         $('#divid').attr('src', e.target.result);
                     }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
          }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/

Comment: Thank you, Siddharth. After Jatin pointed me at the right direction yesterday, I ended up doing exactly what you have replied above.

Comment: hey sorry i didnt saw his comment,and its not my code i also searched for similar post and shared here :)